Microsoft Teams beeps when I mute/unmute in a meeting
Very annoying issue that Microsoft Teams now beeps every time when I mute or unmite myself in a meeting. It never beeped before. The beep is very annoyiny and there is no way stop it?
I also don't know why it started to happen by itself.

I realized the issue started to happen when I started using Plantronics headphones. I confirmed the beep does not happen if I use laptop own speakers. But still a weird issue for which there is no direct settings in Teams but it beeps.
However the solution is to turn off "Sync Device Buttons" (Teams Settings >> Device)  That fixed the issue, no beeps now!
The headphone has volume and mute buttons. This settings syncs with them so if you press it on the headphone or in Teams, they sync with each other and this sync seems to generate the beep.
When this setting is off, you can still use buttons on headphone to mute but it only mutes the mic and not the Teams meeting (software settings) (but effect is obviusly same). The software setting (Teams) and the headphone settings are now independent, not linked (not synced). And no beep!

